# Windows 10 master key folder empty

Tags: windows-10, windows-dpapi, mimikatz

I am currently trying to decrypt my files from my old laptop. I have a backup of the user folder of the old laptop and I am trying to find the old user master key to decrypt my files based on [mimikatz wiki](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/wiki/howto-%7E-decrypt-EFS-files). However, when I look at the master key directory `%appdata%\Microsoft\Protect\<old_user_sid>\`, it is empty. Where does the master key actually stored in?

Answer (score 1):

After looking through mimikatz GitHub issues, I found the [same question asked](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/issues/328#issuecomment-768624267). Apparently, Windows hide the master key (and other system) files.